# What's the difference between the 遇到 and 遇见？

Tags: difference

I can not understand the difference between them. I heard , that it has the same meaning. Can you explain me?can you explain to me in more detail?

Comment: You may be interested to know that there is also 邂 逅, {Xiè Hòu}, meaning, to meet by chance, to run into someone, chance encounter.

Answer (score 4):

You asked this question [whats-the-difference-between-the-听到-听见](https://whats-the-difference-between-the-%E5%90%AC%E5%88%B0-%E5%90%AC%E8%A7%81)

And now you are asking the difference between 遇到 and 遇见

Let me explain [V + 到] and [v+ 见]for you here. 到 and 见 are [result complement](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/result_complement/) (read it and come back)

From that site, you see 到 indicates the action is successful, while 见 indicates the result of the action is 'see'

> 看 means 'to look' but doesn't include the result 'to see'

看见 = look (and actually see)

看到 = (successfully)look (= actually seen)

- 到 is a broadly used result complement, most verbs work with 到 because most verbs can have a successful result
- 见 as a result complement is very specific, it indicates the result of the verb is 'see' or 'detect'

Example:

看见 (look and see)

遇见 (encounter and see)

听见 (hear and detect)

You can replace 见 with 到 in all three examples above

Example:

看到 (successfully see = look and seen)

遇到 (successfully encounter = actually encountered)

听到 (successfully hear = actually heard)

We only use 见 when the result of the action is 'see; detect' and there are not many verb results in 'see', beside the three examples listed so far, I can only come up with

望见 - observe (and see)

夢见 -  dream (and see)

碰见/ 撞见 -  run into (and see)

闻见 - smell (and detect) - *Cantonese*)

Comment: You explained a lot better than I did on the last question.  I wanted to add 會見 meet (and see) and 接見 formal visit/interview (and see) as two more examples of 見 completion.

Comment: @zagrycha  見 in 會見 and 接見 are not result complements Just like 見 in 成見 and 意見. They are parts of a compound word. We know that because we cannot replace 見 with 到 and write 會到 and 接到 without changing the meaning of the word. 見 as a result complement can be replaced with another result complement  到 in every case.

Comment: 會見(gather and see = meet); 接見 (receive and see = receive)

Answer (score 2):

As a mandarin speaker, it is my pleasure to answer your question from my daily life experience.
The two words 遇见 and 遇到 means see something or someone

we may say 在公园，我遇到了特朗普 I met Trump at the park.
or may say 我在公园遇到了特朗普先生 I met Mr.Trump at the park.
they are quite the same when we are trying to see you meet somebody.

But when we see something instead of a living man, it is better for us to use 遇到.
For 我今天遇到了一个技术难题, I encountered a technical challenge today. The grammar is ok for us to say, 我今天遇见了一个技术难题, but better to use 遇到 though.

examples : 遇到危险--遇见坏人         遇到麻烦--遇见敌军
I believe now u know 遇见 are more commonly used for see ***someone*** and 遇到 for ***something***.

Comment: I see you use simplified Chinese so I also use it.

Comment: Was one of your Trump examples supposed to use 遇见? (Also, terrible example – meeting Trump in a park sounds like a nightmare.)

Answer (score 1):

No difference. But 遇见 is often used in the situation when "run into a person", such as "你**遇见**誰了", while 遇到 can use on both occasions when "run into a person or encounter a thing" - "你**遇到**誰了"; "你**遇到**什麼不愉快的事了?"

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the `遇见` and `遇到` are similar, meaning they are interchangeable in most circumstances. In fact, in most Chinese compounds, we can disassemble them into single words with complete meanings.

For example, disassembling the word `遇到` into `遇` and `到`,

| the first word `遇` means 'encounter' |
| --- |
| the second word `到` means your were on the way(emphasizing the action 'go' as well as the status 'at some place'). |

So combining them, means you were on the way at that time, but occasionally you encountered some people or something happening.

on the other hand,  by disassembling the word `遇见`, we can get the words `遇` and `见`.

| The meaning of `遇` is exactly the same as that in `遇到`, |
| --- |
| but the word `见` means you saw some people or something. |

So the whole meaning of `遇见`is you saw(encountered) some people or something accidentally, which implicitly indicates you were on your way to somewhere.

But be cautious that there are still some differences between them:  `遇到` can be used to describe `encountering some bad thing`. such as `遇到坏人`， encounter a bad guy; `遇到车祸`, had a car accident. Whereas it's rarely used in such a way for `遇见`.